# Java Robot class not working from Jenkins

Tags: java, selenium, jenkins, selenium-webdriver, awtrobot

I am automating a scenario(selenium) where i need to enter credentials in Authentication Pop up, which is generated by the APP. I am using java Robot class to perform this function, it runs fine when i run it from my local machine which is a Windows Platform, but it doesn't seem to work when i trigger the build from jenkins. It hangs at a point where you need to enter the Credentials in Authentication Pop up. I think This is because the jenkins slave is an Unix Platform and this has something to do with the cross platform issue. As i am not sure if Unix Supports the Robot class.
    Can somebody suggest me a workaround for this problem ?
Thanks in advance!!

Comment: Can you post how you are passing the authentication credentials in popup window?

Answer (score 0):

The problem might be that you are testing on a headless server? Make sure your are not using firefox or chrome driver. Try to use the **HtmlUnitWebDriver** driver instead.